# Build dependency tree object from flat array in javascript with child_id references

Tags: javascript, list, tree, depth-first-search

I have a list of items, and I need to compile a list of all dependencies in a given item and the tree of dependencies. The list is not ordered, and each item contains an `id` and `dep` where dep is the reference to another item that's a child of the given item.

Each id can have multiple deps and I need to be able to detect circular dependencies anywhere in the tree.

I built an example list that would contain most of use cases:

Input:

```
const input = [
  { id: '1' },
  { id: '2' },
  { id: '3' },
  { id: '4', dep: '1' },
  { id: '5', dep: '2' },
  { id: '6', dep: '3' },
  { id: '7', dep: '4' },
  { id: '8', dep: '5' },
  { id: '8', dep: '1' },
  { id: '8', dep: '4' },
  { id: '9', dep: '8' },
  { id: '10', dep: '8' },
  { id: '11', dep: '10' },
  { id: '12', dep: '11' },
  { id: '14', dep: '13' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '13', dep: '17' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '15', dep: '13' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '16', dep: '13' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '17', dep: '16' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '18', dep: '13' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '19', dep: '20' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '20', dep: '14' }, // Circular reference
  { id: '21', dep: '22' },
  { id: '17', dep: '21' },
  { id: '16', dep: '14' }
];
```

The expected result doesn't need to be exatcly this one, but something similar.
Expected Result:

```
const output = {
    '1': null,
    '2': null,
    '3': null,
    '4': { allDeps: [ '1' ], tree: { '1': null }},
    '5': { allDeps: [ '2' ], tree: { '2': null }},
    '6': { allDeps: [ '3' ], tree: { '3': null }},
    '7': {
        allDeps: [ '4', '1' ],
        tree: { '4': { '1': null }}
    },
    '8': {
        allDeps: [ '5', '2', '1', '4' ],
        tree: {
            '5': { '2': null },
            '4': { '1': null },
            '1': null
        }
    },
    '9': {
        allDeps: [ '8', '5', '2', '1', '4' ],
        tree: { '8': { '5': { '2': null }, '4': { '1': null }, '1': null }}
    },
    '10': {
        allDeps: [ '8', '5', '2', '1', '4' ],
        tree: { '8': { '5': { '2': null }, '4': { '1': null }, '1': null }}
    },
    '11': {
        allDeps: [ '10', '8', '5', '2', '1', '4' ],
        tree: { '10': { '8': { '5': { '2': null }, '4': { '1': null }, '1': null }}}
    },
    '12': {
        allDeps: [ '11', '10', '8', '5', '2', '1', '4' ],
        tree: { '11': { '10': { '8': { '5': { '2': null }, '4': { '1': null }, '1': null }}}}
    },
    '13': {
        allDeps: [ '17', '16', '13', '22', '21', '14' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '13', '14' ]],
        tree: {
            '17': {
                '16': {
                    '13': 'circular',
                    '14': { '13': 'circular' }
                },
                '21': { '22': null }
            }
        }
    },
    '14': {
        allDeps: [ '13', '17', '16', '22', '21', '13', '14' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '14', '16' ]],
        tree: {
            '13': {
                '17': {
                    '16': {
                        '13': 'circular',
                        '14': 'circular'
                    },
                    '21': { '22': null }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '15': {
        allDeps: [ '13', '17', '16', '22', '21', '13', '14' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '13', '14' ]],
        tree: {
            '13': {
                '17': {
                    '16': {
                        '13': 'circular',
                        '14': { '13': 'circular' }
                    },
                    '21': { '22': null }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '16': {
        allDeps: [ '13', '17', '16', '14', '22', '21' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '17', '16' ], [ '17', '16' ]],
        tree: {
            '13': {
                '17': {
                    '16': 'circular',
                    '21': { '22': null }
                }
            },
            '14': {
                '13': {
                    '17': {
                        '16': 'circular',
                        '21': { '22': null }
                    },
                    '21': { '22': null }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '17': {
        allDeps: [ '16', '13', '17', '21', '22', '14' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '17' ], [ '13', '17' ]],
        tree: {
            '16': {
                '13': { '17': 'circular' },
                '14': {
                    '13': { '17': 'circular' }
                }
            },
            '21': { '22': null }
        }
    },
    '18': {
        allDeps: [ '13', '17', '16', '21', '22', '14' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '14', '13' ]],
        tree: {
            '13': {
                '17': {
                    '16': {
                        '13': 'circular',
                        '14': { '13': 'circular' }
                    },
                    '21': { '22': null }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '19': {
        allDeps: [ '20', '14', '13', '17', '16', '22', '21' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '14', '16' ]],
        tree: {
            '20': {
                '14': {
                    '13': {
                        '17': {
                            '16': {
                                '13': 'circular',
                                '14': 'circular'
                            },
                            '21': { '22': null }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '20': {
        allDeps: [ '14', '13', '17', '16', '21', '22' ],
        hasCircular: true,
        circularIds: [[ '13', '16' ], [ '16', '14' ]],
        tree: {
            '14': {
                '13': {
                    '17': {
                        '16': {
                            '13': 'circular',
                            '14': 'circular'
                        },
                        '21': { '22': null }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    '21': {
        allDeps: [ '22' ],
        tree: { '22': null }
    },
    '22': null
};
```

I've built the expected result by hand, so something can be wrong there, but I think it accomplishes the goal of expressing the idea. Also, the structure is not final, I do need the full flat list of all dependencies, the identification of the existence of circular dependency and where that happens, and a tree with parent/child structure. If that's an array of objects or an object is not relevant.

The real data have multiple rows for each id as you can see with `id=8`, and the full dataset has hundreds of thousands of rows.

The code I built so far can start building the allDeps property, but it doesn't detect circular dependencies, and I didn't find a way to build the tree part.

I found a bunch of references of tree-search algos, but they all work with parent_id instead of child_id, like the case I have.

I spent a few days trying to create the code using DFS, but I was not successful, so I'm asking for help.

The code below is the further I could go, and it even has some optimizations. Please don't restrain yourselves by my code:

```
function getMap(fullList) {
  const portifolioMap = {};
  const itemsWithDependencies = new Set(); // This exists so i can build the null values first as an optimization

  const portfolioCache = {}; // This is a cache of all the items that have the same id so i dont need to loop a bunch of times later
  const emptyRow = { allDeps: new Set() };

  // get all unique ids
  const uniqueIds = fullList.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc.add(item.id);

    if(item.dep) {
      acc.add(item.dep);
      itemsWithDependencies.add(item.id);
    }

    if(!portfolioCache[item.id]) {
      portfolioCache[item.id] = [];
    }

    if(item.dep && !portfolioCache[item.dep]) {
      portfolioCache[item.dep] = [];
    }

    portfolioCache[item.id].push(item);

    return acc;
  }, new Set());

  function visitNode(firstNodeId, node) {
    if(!node) return;

    if(!portifolioMap[firstNodeId]) {
      portifolioMap[firstNodeId] = Object.assign({}, emptyRow);
    }

    if(node.dep) {
      portifolioMap[firstNodeId].allDeps.add(node.dep);
    }

    const allItemsFromThisDep = portfolioCache[node.dep] || [];

    allItemsFromThisDep.forEach(thisNode => visitNode(firstNodeId, thisNode));

    return;
  }

  function buildTree(id) {
    const allItemsFromThisCnpj = portfolioCache[id];

    if(!allItemsFromThisCnpj.length) return null;

    if(!portifolioMap[id]) {
      portifolioMap[id] = Object.assign({}, emptyRow);
    }

    allItemsFromThisCnpj.forEach((item) => visitNode(id, item));
    return portifolioMap[id];
  }

  // lopp all the unique ids
  uniqueIds.forEach((id) => {
    if(!itemsWithDependencies.has(id)) {
      portifolioMap[id] = null;
      return;
    }

    portifolioMap[id] = buildTree(id);
  });

  return portifolioMap;
}
```

Comment: btw, you have an array of objects, not [JSON](https://json.org/)`, which is a parsable string.

Comment: why don't you take for `'13'` all ids for `circularIds`, like `['17', '16', '13']`?

Comment: The object I built is just an example. There will be several circular dependencies, it is just that in my example, that's the only row with circular, but with the real data that won't be the case. And I do need to have the full list since I need to throw all this into a database. There will be an endpoint like "Give me all the dependencies of 18" and the database need to have the full list.

Comment: Why not let the database derive that dynamically with a recursive query? It seems a bad pattern to store all this duplicated information in the DB. If there is a node that roots a large subtree, and there are  ancestors of that node, then you will duplicate that subtree  times. This could quickly consume exponential amounts of database space.

Comment: Your example has no dependencies from a node in a cycle where the dependent node is not in a cycle: does this never happen? Your example has no cycles nested in cycles? Does this never happen? For instance, if your input also has `{ id: 17, dep: 21}, { id: 16, dep: 14}` how would that impact the expected output?

Comment: @trincot I edited the post to add those rows to the input. Let me know if that answers your question. Regarding the database question, this is just the first step, I will do a lot of calculations with that tree (and the content of those items) later on, and I'm afraid calculating that entire tree on every request would be too much. And I can always store cached versions of the data elsewhere other than the database if that ends up being a problem. That being said, I will be glad to read any material on the subject if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for adding that to your input, but now your output seems to lack information. For instance, for node 13 (and others), shouldn't nodes 21 and 22 be in their tree and dependants? And for node 17 there is no mention of the cycle via 16-14-17. Just two examples of missing info.

Comment: @trincot Thank you for pointing that out. Indeed I didn't make all the necessary changes in the first case. I changed the structure a bit and added the cases you pointed. I built that by hand, and it's late at night, so I might have missed something else. Please let me know if that's the case! Thank you again for pointing out the issues!

Comment: @LuanMuniz i can tell you put a good amount of effort into your post. i'm hoping my answer gets you 90% of the way there. if you have follow-up questions, don't be shy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edge**

Your input is defined in terms of a graph's *edges*. We will define a type for your identifiers, `tident`, and a type for the edges, `tedge`. Your question isn't tagged with TypeScript but thinking in types will assist us along the way. A vanilla JavaScript version is available at the end of the post -

```
type tident = number
type tnullable<T> = T | null
type tedge = { id: tident, dep: tnullable<tident> }
```

Now we type your `input` as `Array<tedge>` -

```
const input: Array<tedge> = [
  { id: 1, dep: null },
  { id: 2, dep: null },
  { id: 3, dep: null },
  { id: 4, dep: 1 },
  { id: 5, dep: 2 },
  …
]
```

**graph**

Next we functions to construct a `graph` using `addEdge` -

```
type tgraph = Map<tident, Set<tident>>

const graph = (): tgraph => {
  return new Map()
}

const addEdge = (t: tgraph, { id, dep }: tedge): tgraph => {
  let r = new Map(t)
  if (!r.has(id)) r.set(id, new Set)
  if (dep == null) return r
  if (!r.has(dep)) r.set(dep, new Set)
  r.set(id, new Set(r.get(id)!).add(dep))
  return r
}
```

Your graph `g` can be constructed by writing -

```
const g: tgraph = input.reduce(addEdge, graph())
```

```js
Map {
  1 => Set {}, 
  2 => Set {}, 
  3 => Set {}, 
  4 => Set {1}, 
  5 => Set {2}, 
  6 => Set {3}, 
  7 => Set {4}, 
  8 => Set {5, 1, 4}, 
  9 => Set {8}, 
  10 => Set {8}, 
  11 => Set {10}, 
  12 => Set {11}, 
  14 => Set {13}, 
  13 => Set {17}, 
  17 => Set {16, 21}, 
  15 => Set {13}, 
  16 => Set {13, 14}, 
  18 => Set {13}, 
  19 => Set {20}, 
  20 => Set {14}, 
  21 => Set {22}, 
  22 => Set {}
}
```

**deps**

Now it's easy to write the smaller functions our graph needs, such as `deps` -

```
const deps = (t: tgraph, id: tident): Array<tident> => {
  const seen: Set<tident> = new Set
  function *loop(id: tident): Generator<tident> {
    if (seen.has(id)) return
    seen.add(id)
    yield id
    for (const dep of t.get(id) ?? new Set)
      yield *loop(dep)
  }
  const res = new Set(loop(id))
  res.delete(id)
  return Array.from(res)
}
```

Let's preview some `deps` queries -

```
console.log(deps(g, 1))
console.log(deps(g, 14))
console.log(deps(g, 18))
```

Notice unlike your output, an identifier will never be listed as a dependency of itself -

```js
[] 
[13, 17, 16, 21, 22]
[13, 17, 16, 14, 21, 22]
```

**node**

Now let's write the `node` function for our graph -

```
type tnode = { id: tident, deps: ttree | "circular" } 
type ttree = Array<tnode>

const node = (t: tgraph, id: tident): tnode => {
  function loop(id: tident, seen: Set<tident>): tnode {
    if (seen.has(id)) return  { id, deps: "circular" }
    return {
      id,
      deps: Array
        .from(t.get(id) ?? new Set as Set<tident>)
        .map(dep => loop(dep, new Set(seen).add(id)))
    }
  }
  return loop(id, new Set)
}
```

Let's query a couple nodes -

```
console.log(node(g, 1))
console.log(node(g, 16))
```

```js
{
  "id": 1,
  "deps": []
}
```

```js
{
  "id": 16,
  "deps": [
    {
      "id": 13,
      "deps": [
        {
          "id": 17,
          "deps": [
            {
              "id": 16,
              "deps": "circular"
            },
            {
              "id": 21,
              "deps": [
                {
                  "id": 22,
                  "deps": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 14,
      "deps": [
        {
          "id": 13,
          "deps": [
            {
              "id": 17,
              "deps": [
                {
                  "id": 16,
                  "deps": "circular"
                },
                {
                  "id": 21,
                  "deps": [
                    {
                      "id": 22,
                      "deps": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**reaching the goal**

Now that we've divided the complex task, we can combine the smaller parts into a more sophisticated solution -

```
type tinfo = { id: tident, allDeps: Array<tident>, tree: tnode }

const info: Array<tinfo> = Array.from(
  g.keys(),
  id => ({
    id,
    allDeps: deps(g, id),
    tree: node(g, id)
  })
)

console.log("info", info)
```

Get ready to scroll -

```js
[{
  "id": 1,
  "allDeps": [],
  "tree": {
    "id": 1,
    "deps": []
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "allDeps": [],
  "tree": {
    "id": 2,
    "deps": []
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "allDeps": [],
  "tree": {
    "id": 3,
    "deps": []
  }
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "allDeps": [
    1
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 4,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "deps": []
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "allDeps": [
    2
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 5,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "deps": []
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "allDeps": [
    3
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 6,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "deps": []
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "allDeps": [
    4,
    1
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 7,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 4,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "deps": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "allDeps": [
    5,
    2,
    1,
    4
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 8,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 5,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 2,
            "deps": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "deps": []
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "deps": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "allDeps": [
    8,
    5,
    2,
    1,
    4
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 9,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 2,
                "deps": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 1,
            "deps": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "deps": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "allDeps": [
    8,
    5,
    2,
    1,
    4
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 10,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 8,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 5,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 2,
                "deps": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 1,
            "deps": []
          },
          {
            "id": 4,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "deps": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "allDeps": [
    10,
    8,
    5,
    2,
    1,
    4
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 11,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 10,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 8,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 5,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 2,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 1,
                "deps": []
              },
              {
                "id": 4,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 1,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "allDeps": [
    11,
    10,
    8,
    5,
    2,
    1,
    4
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 12,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 11,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 10,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 8,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 5,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 2,
                        "deps": []
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 1,
                    "deps": []
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 4,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 1,
                        "deps": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 14,
  "allDeps": [
    13,
    17,
    16,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 14,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 16,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 13,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 14,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 21,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 13,
  "allDeps": [
    17,
    16,
    14,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 13,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 17,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 16,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 13,
                "deps": "circular"
              },
              {
                "id": 14,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 13,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 21,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 22,
                "deps": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 17,
  "allDeps": [
    16,
    13,
    14,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 17,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 16,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 13,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 17,
                "deps": "circular"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": 14,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 13,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 17,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 22,
            "deps": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 15,
  "allDeps": [
    13,
    17,
    16,
    14,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 15,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 16,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 13,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 14,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 13,
                        "deps": "circular"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 21,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 16,
  "allDeps": [
    13,
    17,
    21,
    22,
    14
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 16,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 16,
                "deps": "circular"
              },
              {
                "id": 21,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 13,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 17,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 16,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 21,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 22,
                        "deps": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 18,
  "allDeps": [
    13,
    17,
    16,
    14,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 18,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 13,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 17,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 16,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 13,
                    "deps": "circular"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 14,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 13,
                        "deps": "circular"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "id": 21,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 22,
                    "deps": []
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 19,
  "allDeps": [
    20,
    14,
    13,
    17,
    16,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 19,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 20,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 14,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 13,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 17,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 16,
                        "deps": [
                          {
                            "id": 13,
                            "deps": "circular"
                          },
                          {
                            "id": 14,
                            "deps": "circular"
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 21,
                        "deps": [
                          {
                            "id": 22,
                            "deps": []
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 20,
  "allDeps": [
    14,
    13,
    17,
    16,
    21,
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 20,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 14,
        "deps": [
          {
            "id": 13,
            "deps": [
              {
                "id": 17,
                "deps": [
                  {
                    "id": 16,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 13,
                        "deps": "circular"
                      },
                      {
                        "id": 14,
                        "deps": "circular"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 21,
                    "deps": [
                      {
                        "id": 22,
                        "deps": []
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 21,
  "allDeps": [
    22
  ],
  "tree": {
    "id": 21,
    "deps": [
      {
        "id": 22,
        "deps": []
      }
    ]
  }
}, {
  "id": 22,
  "allDeps": [],
  "tree": {
    "id": 22,
    "deps": []
  }
}]
```

**remarks**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. That means avoiding things like mutation, variable reassignments, and other side effects. It also emphasizes isolating behaviors and composing small programs to build large ones. Hopefully you were able to see the strengths of this style applied to this problem.

I didn't keep your proposed output because it has several problems -

1. A node should never be listed as a dependency of itself
2. Objects should have *known* properties. That means you should always favor `{ name: "foo", value: "bar" }` over `{ foo: "bar" }`.
3. Additional properties like `hasCircular` and `circularDeps` are redundant, derived state. If you want to include them, this is left as an exercise for the reader. Write `hasCircular(t: tgraph): bool` and `circularDeps(t: tgraph): Array<tedge>`, and finally update `info` to use the smaller functions -

**without typescript**

Here's the vanilla `graph.js` module, as compiled by typescript -

```js
export const graph = () => {
  return new Map();
};

export const addEdge = (t, { id, dep }) => {
  let r = new Map(t);
  if (!r.has(id))
    r.set(id, new Set);
  if (dep == null)
    return r;
  if (!r.has(dep))
    r.set(dep, new Set);
  r.set(id, new Set(r.get(id)).add(dep));
  return r;
};

export const deps = (t, id) => {
  const seen = new Set;
  function* loop(id) {
    if (seen.has(id))
      return;
    seen.add(id);
    yield id;
    for (const dep of t.get(id) ?? new Set)
      yield* loop(dep);
  }
  const res = new Set(loop(id));
  res.delete(id);
  return Array.from(res);
};

export const node = (t, id) => {
  function loop(id, seen) {
    if (seen.has(id))
      return { id, deps: "circular" };
    return {
      id,
      deps: Array
        .from(t.get(id) ?? new Set)
        .map(dep => loop(dep, new Set(seen).add(id)))
    };
  }
  return loop(id, new Set);
};
```

**demo**

Verify the result in your own browser at [typescript playground](https://tsplay.dev/WG8bXw).

Comment: using well-defined types, our program output is easily machine-consumable without having to type-check properties along the way. regardless of whether you choose to use typescript, i suggest you always reach for this as a goal.

Comment: Thank you for your response! It already helps me a lot! I will pay attention for the points you mention for sure! That being said if you check `node(g, 16)`, you will find that it doesn't build the entire tree for 14. Since it has already visited 13 from a previous branch, it just says `13:'circular'` which is not necessarily true, the tree is missing nodes for 17 and 18 too. Also, there is `node(g, 8)` because it says 1 is circular when it's not since it has already visited 1 from another branch too. False circulars like that are my main issue. Thank you again for the response!

Comment: thanks for the review @LuanMuniz. I modified the `node` function to match your specification. The fix is to use an independent set for each branch of the `loop` recursion. I also modified `deps` to guarantee that an identifier will never list a dependency of itself.